# Unknown module(s) in QT: svg

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qmake, qtsvg

Added QT += svg and I tried just QT += svg and greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += svg to the .pro solution file and ran qmake from inside the QtCreator and got this error:

> error: Unknown module(s) in QT: svg

Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10. How to check this?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You are lacking the installation of the the QtSvg library. Try to install them on your Ubuntu 13.10 in the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5*
```

Comment: oddly enough I did not see the `dev` packages in synaptic when I entered `qt svg`

Comment: In Fedora it is `sudo dnf install qt5-qtsvg-devel`.

Comment: Just doing `sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev` resolves to all the dependencies needed by pgModeler.

Comment: @zerobandwidth This in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @lpapp how to install the module to a statically built version of Qt in Windows (see my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097920/how-to-install-or-add-qt-qtsvg-module-to-the-statically-built-qt-framework)

Answer (score 15):

Debian Stretch:

```
sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev
```

Fedora (courtesy of @robin-green):

```
sudo dnf install qt5-qtsvg-devel
```

Answer (score 3):

Because zsh complains to me about "no matches found" when using lpapp's answer, I would like to add here:
On Debian Systems one can get the required library for **release builds** via:

```
sudo apt install libqt5svg5
```

and if one also wants to build a **debug build** one requires:

```
sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev
```

additionally.