# SVG icons dont show up in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, svg, qt5

I am using SVG icons in my application from the ressource file, but when I run the app the icons are just not displayed. Using jpg icons in the same way works pretty fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problem

Since [Qt5.1](https://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.1) the framework has been [modularized](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modules.html). 
Most likely you are missing the svg module. The application will still compile without complaining.

### Solution

Make sure the SVG module is installed on your system and linked (with qmake [(Howto)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt), cmake [(Howto)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) or plain make). If it was linked successfully [QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats) will list SVG.

Comment: [Instruction to install qt5-svg on some Linux OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098805/unknown-modules-in-qt-svg).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using cmake, you need something like this to link Svg Qt libraries.

```
find_package(Qt5Svg REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries( ${APP_NAME} Qt5::Svg )
```

A full example (sorry ManuelSchneid3r) could be the following one.

```
## application name
set( APP_NAME "myapp" )

## project name
project( ${APP_NAME} )

## require a minimum version of CMake
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR )

## add definitions, compiler switches, etc.
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -Wall -O2 )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -g )

## include (or not) the full compiler output
SET( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF )

# find Qt
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Svg REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Svg_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# The AUTOUIC target property controls whether cmake(1) inspects the
# C++ files in the target to determine if they require uic to be run,
# and to create rules to execute uic at the appropriate time.
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

## sources
file( GLOB MAIN_SRC *.cpp )
set( SOURCES ${MAIN_SRC} )

## executable
add_executable( ${APP_NAME} ${SOURCES} )

## link
target_link_libraries( ${APP_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Svg )
```

Comment: This example is not sufficient at all. Thats why I referenced the [qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html). What about definitions, compiler flags, include dirs, MOC etc?

Comment: Well, sorry, I only put a minimal example.