# Cannot install pgmodeler

Tags: postgresql, pgmodeler

I got problem while compiling pgmodeler on Mac. I typed `qmake pgmodeler.pro` in binary folder, and got the following error:

```
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:21: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:24: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:103: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:104: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:105: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:106: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:107: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:108: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:109: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:110: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:111: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:112: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
 /Users/****/Applications/pgmodelerunzip/pgmodeler-0.8.1-beta/pgmodeler.pri:113: defined(function, type): unexpected type [var].
```

Comment: Here's a guide I wrote on how to compile pgModeler 0.9.3 on Ubuntu https://medium.com/@mglaving/how-to-compile-pgmodeler-0-9-3-on-ubuntu-20-04-19f045ec5b1d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you compile pgModeler? At this moment I cannot help you more than just describe my case.

### My road to compile pgModeler

I had almost same issue on my Linux Mint 17.1 (x64). I followed this tutorial: http://www.pgmodeler.com.br/wiki/doku.php?id=installation

First I've installed some required packages using apt:
`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev libxml2-dev`

Next I've downloaded newest version of pgModeler from https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler/tags

In Linux Mint's repo there was Qt4 version only, so I had to install Qt5 using installer from official Qt site. I've just downloaded Community version and followed the instructions.
Next I just needed to specify path to new Qt libraries by adding to my PATH in `/etc/environment` (`~/.bashrc` is also a great place for it) `$QT_DIR/Tools/QtCreator/bin` and `$QT_DIR/5.4/gcc_64/bin` (those are in my case, you might change it to similar ones).

I was left with only type `qmake pgmodeler.pro && make && sudo make install` in a terminal and wait for end of the process.

*My english leaves a lot to be desired, so please send me some corrections.*

Comment: I didn't use Qt5.  I had used Qt4 , "qmake " indicate Qt4 in my environment . So I modified symbolic link in /usr/local/bin/ . Thank you very much.

Comment: I succeed command 'qmake pgmodeler.pro && make && sudo make install' and create pgModeler.app . But I get error when I open pgModeler.app  .  So I'll try install again in this week . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial link in `kamarkiewicz`'s answer goes nowhere now, so I'll just post here what I *think* is the complete list of packages you'll need to do the build in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 libpq5 libpq-dev clang libxml2-dev qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev
```

The PostgreSQL stuff at the beginning is obvious but I figured I'd mention it anyway. After those:

- **`libpq5`** and **`libpq-dev`** are the PostgreSQL development libraries.
- **`clang`** is the compiler used in the pgModeler build process.
- **`libxml2-dev`** is required by pgModeler.
- pgModeler must be built with QT5, so installing **`qt5-default`** gets you  QT5 development packages and sets it as the default QT version.

  - Test this on the command line with `qmake -v` and verify that it says it's using QT5.
- The `SVG` module for QT is required; **`libqt5svg5-dev`** provides this.

  - *see* [Answer 21100312](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100312)

If anyone happens to discover other packages that are required that I already had installed, please comment on this answer and I'll be happy to edit it.