# How to install or add qt QtSvg module to the statically built Qt framework

Tags: qt

My Qt5.7 is statically built with VS2015 in windows 10. The building configurations are as follows:

```
configure -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2015 
-qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop 
-qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-odbc -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license 
-make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

It is found that the built Qt has no `QtSVG` module after I type `QT += svg` in a `.pro` file.  Does the building process build all Qt modules? I obtained the Qt source from here`[qt official releases][1]`

I want to add the `QtSvg` module, but do not want to rebuild the whole Qt, which is too time-consuming. Is there any simple way to add the module?

That is to install the module to the qtbase include folder, more specifically, C:\Qt\5.7.0\qtbase\include\QtSvg.

Comment: just download the svg submodule, open a CMD and run `qmake`, then `make` and finally `make install` (with administrator permission if necessary)

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thanks for your comments! but I did not find where to download the submodule (would you mind providing a weblink for that)? is there any version compatibility requirement for Qt5.7?

Comment: https://github.com/qt/qtsvg/tree/5.7

Comment: @eyllanesc I have downloaded the module and unzip it to a folder. For the installation you mentioned, could you please provide more detailed guidelines to walk me through the process? I have launched the cmd, and type 'qmake', what is next before 'make install'. Do I need navigate the directory to the one where unzipped QtSVG is located? Thanks in advance!

Comment: all commands must be done when the CMD is located in the unzipped file folder

Comment: @eyllanesc Runing 'make install' results in an error: ''make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'. What do you think cause the error?

Comment: that indicates that the path of qmake is not in environment variables, so the solution is to find the qmake where you installed Qt and execute: `/path/of/qmake.exe`

Comment: @eyllanesc: qmake.exe is located at 'C:\Qt\5.7.0\qtbase\bin' that was put in the Environment Variables. There is no issue with running 'qmake' in cmd, but following which 'make install' fails to proceed due to the above error.

Comment: you are right, in linux use make, in your case it must be `nmake`

Comment: or `jom` or `mingw32-make`. see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for you guiding me! It seems the QtSvg module has been installed that way. But #include <QtSvg> still cannot be successfully included in a c++ file (qt += svg is set in the .pro file) for some reason. QtSvg: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, are you sure it was installed correctly? I also recommend closing and reopening your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186377/discussion-between-jingweimo-and-eyllanesc).